# Working with XML POST requests in Zend Framework2

Tags: xml, zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend Framework 2 and I have to use a XML POST request to call a webservice.

I've gone through ZF2 documentation and found out that I can use the following.

```
Zend\DOM\Query  (to parse the xml respose)
Zend\Http\Client 
Zend\XmlRpc\Client
```

My xml post request is a lengthy one. I can start this with `Zend\Http\Client` and what I can't understand is where to store the xml request? Is is convenient if I keep the xml data in the code itself or do I have to store the xml requst on another document and load the document when calling the webservice? Also I need to change the values of the parameters of the xml post request per webservice call.

What do I need to do? I think I've not grabbed the basics of XML POST requests. But I could not find a proper answer in the internet to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're posting a large amount of XML data that is mostly the same each time, it might make sense to store it on the file system, but you could do it either way - do whatever makes the most sense for your app.

Although you can use DOM query to parse XML, you might want to look at [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), which is PHP's native XML parsing lib.